# xp-pen not working ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, graphics-tablet

I had my xp-pen G640 working great on ubuntu 16.04 with the digimend-kernel-drivers.

But now that I updated to ubuntu 20.04 the tablet is recognized but is mapped all wrong.

It moves the curser and selects when I click and hold the buttom button, the top button and tapping the pen does nothing.

```
xinput
```

it shows up 4 times

```
  Virtual core pointer  
  ⎜   ↳ XP-PEN STAR G640 Mouse                      id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
  ⎜   ↳ XP-PEN STAR G640 Mouse                      id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
  ⎜   ↳ XP-PEN STAR G640 Pen Pen (0)                id=28   [slave  pointer  (2)]
  ⎣ Virtual core keyboard 
        ↳ XP-PEN STAR G640 Pen                      id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The same happened on an XP-Pen Star 03: working perfectly out of the box in Ubuntu 18.04 but not in a fresh install of 20.04. The input was recognised in v20.04 multiple times in `xinput` (as `TABLET 1060N`) and the tablet light worked when moving the pen or touching buttons, but no movement on the screen, and installing the original drivers downloaded from XP-Pen didn't help either.

I tried a simplified version of this approach: https://blog.simos.info/how-to-setup-the-huion-430p-drawing-tablet-on-ubuntu-20-04/ and it worked.

In essence, edit this file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-wacom.conf` (e.g. `sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-wacom.conf`) and add the name of your device, as identified using `xinput`. Unlike in the link above, I simply added the name of my device as 'or' in one of the existing sections, e.g., from:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom serial class"
    MatchProduct "Serial Wacom Tablet"
    Driver "wacom"
EndSection
```

to

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom serial class"
    MatchProduct "Serial Wacom Tablet|TABLET 1060N"
    Driver "wacom"
EndSection
```

Log out and in again, and *voilà*.