# XP-Pen driver/app is unable to detect device on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, wacom, xinput, graphics-tablet

##### Problem Summary

So, when I connect my **Star 03 graphic tablet** to the system, the inbuilt `wacom` drivers in Ubuntu 22.04 *kind of* detect the device. However, when I install the official driver from the [xp-pen website](https://www.xp-pen.com/download/star-03.html), the accompanying app is unable to detect the device.

Here are some screenshots to explain the issue:

Wacom driver detects the device as a Tablet:
[image]

However, XP-Pen official driver app cannot:
[image]

##### System Information

Here is the output from `xinput`:

```shell
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ *****                                     id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ *****                                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ *****                                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ XP-PEN MOUSE                              id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ UC-Logic TABLET 1060N Pad                 id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ *****                                     id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ *****                                     id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ *****                                     id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ *****                                     id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ *****                                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ *****                                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ *****                                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ *****                                     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ *****                                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ XP-PEN ERASER                             id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ XP-PEN STYLUS                             id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ UC-Logic TABLET 1060N Pen                 id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

(*I have hidden other devices due to privacy concerns*)

Now, the **XP-PEN** entries above came from the official driver, but, the **UC-Logic...** entry pops up only when I plug in the device.

##### Potential Solution

Somehow I think the solution involves creating the correct configuration file at:
`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` where currently the `70-wacom.conf` file somehow handles the device. I think we need to create something called `xp-pen.conf` to handle the device and map it to the official driver/app.
(Idea taken from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1330907)!)

##### Emphasis

**The device works as expected under the default wacom driver, I want it to work with the official xp-pen driver**

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems with Wacom Cintiq pro 24 for several years. At boot up Ubuntu does not recognise any of the pen tools. I discovered a work around - switch off the monitor and on again. Ubuntu then recognises the tools and works fine. Disconnecting and reconnecting your device might wake up the device driver.

It is irritating so if anyone can come up with a better solution I would also be interested.